# JSP/HTML Page to PDF conversion

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf

How to convert to PDF from my JSP/HTML file?.

I want to convert a particular part of my webpage to a PDF file. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML files to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Take a good look at booth [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) and [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/).  No matter what you use, you'll probably have to do a little fiddling.

Answer (score 2):

I used [HTMLDoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) a couple of years ago and had pretty good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  It is a command line utility that can be provided an html file or web address and a save location for the pdf.  Very easy to use and utilizes the same rendering engine as safari.  Works MUCH better than many of the other parsers that I have used (that don't always support CSS and other advanced layout features.

Comment: Can we use wkhtmltopdf without installing it in the system. They have no documentation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [html2ps (Perl)](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) or [html2ps (PHP)](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm). However, none of the two is implemented in Java.

You might also want to read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html).

Answer (score 0):

flying saucer library is the best one to use. It works on top of itext and makes the task of conversion very easy.