# Print/save full webpage as PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, activex, pdf-generation

I need a method to be able to print/save the current full webpage as a PDF.

I know it can be done if I download a PDF printer and print to that; but I need it to be done without the user having to do anything other than click a button in a webpage.

I can't do it via PHP as the page is all client side content, so I'm guessing an ActiveX component?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.freepdfconvert.com](http://www.freepdfconvert.com) - they also have a javascript one click PDF download from any page.

Comment: Hi thanks but the content is client side so simply passing the URL won't work as the user won't have created the content!