# html to pdf in java plugin

Tags: java, html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)
>   [List of HTML to PDF converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters)

We want an java plugin to convert html to pdf, that will integrate with our app. is that possible with any java plugins?, we dont want to purchase it every time especially number of users for one app something like that. we will integrate that plugin with our app. we are not going to show that there plugin inside our app.but there is need of printing html on browser and as well need to produce pdf for that HTML in our app. we want plugin for our application. is there any java /java server plugin .

Please let us know that if this suitable to our requirements. any reply that would be great help.

Thanks and Regards
kumar kasimala

Answer (score 1):

You can use itext library for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PDF Converter services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services.aspx). It supports loads of formats including HTML and works from any Web Services capable environment including Java and .net.

Here are some examples:

- [Converting using the web services interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html)
- [Converting HTML](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html)

Note that the articles may mention SharePoint a couple of times. Don't worry, the product is not tied to SharePoint, it just happens to be used a lot in that environment.

Big disclaimer, I worked on the product so I am obviously biased about how fantastic the product is :-)