# how to convert html content to pdf?

Tags: html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML Files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

i designed  online exam certificate using html code now i want to convert that certificate to pdf please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If its a one-off, you can use a pdf printer like http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/