# How to export html page to pdf format?

Tags: java, html, pdf

I have to offer some export functions to my website such as CSV or PDF. Is there a powerful and free tool for Java to convert HTML pages to PDF format?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using [`Flying Saucer API`](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) with [`iText PDF`](http://itextpdf.com) you can convert HTML content to PDF.
Following examples help you in understanding, to some extent, conversion of XHTML to PDF.

**Examples Using Flying Saucer API**:
You require following libraries:

- core-renderer.jar
- iText-2.0.8.jar

You can find these resources in [`flyingsaucer-R8.zip`](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/downloads/list).

**Example1: Using XML Resource**:

```
// if you have html source in hand, use it to generate document object
Document document = XMLResource.load( new ByteArrayInputStream( yourXhtmlContentAsString.getBytes() ) ).getDocument();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument( document, null );

renderer.layout();

String fileNameWithPath = outputFileFolder + "PDF-XhtmlRendered.pdf";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameWithPath );
renderer.createPDF( fos );
fos.close();
System.out.println( "File 1: '" + fileNameWithPath + "' created." );
```

**Example2: Using XHTML direct input to Document**:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

// if you have html source in hand, use it to generate document object
renderer.setDocumentFromString( yourXhtmlContentAsString );
renderer.layout();

String fileNameWithPath = outputFileFolder + "PDF-FromHtmlString.pdf";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameWithPath );
renderer.createPDF( fos );
fos.close();

System.out.println( "File 2: '" + fileNameWithPath + "' created." );
```

**Examples Using iText API**:
You require following libraries:

- core-renderer.jar
- itextpdf-5.2.1.jar

You can find these resources at [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/).

**Example3: Using HTML Worker**:

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document =
        new com.itextpdf.text.Document( com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4 );
String fileNameWithPath = outputFileFolder + "PDF-HtmlWorkerParsed.pdf";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameWithPath );
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter =
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance( document, fos );

document.open();

//**********************************************************
// if required, you can add document meta data
document.addAuthor( "Ravinder" );
//document.addCreator( creator );
document.addSubject( "HtmlWoker Parsed Pdf from iText" );
document.addCreationDate();
document.addTitle( "HtmlWoker Parsed Pdf from iText" );
//**********************************************************/

com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker htmlWorker =
        new com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker( document );
htmlWorker.parse( new StringReader( sb.toString() ) );

document.close();
fos.close();

System.out.println( "File 3: '" + fileNameWithPath + "' created." );
```

Comment: sorry for a late reply.....                                           htmlWorker.parse( new StringReader( sb.toString() ) );
                                                                    I'm getting a JSP output...how do I convert that to HTML. I think sb is the XHTML/HTML content. Is that right?

Comment: Arabic letters is not shown with your code. Is there a way ?

Comment: @user4757345: Did you see that the `'html'` content type is set like `"text/html; charset=utf-8"`. Basically it is the HTML instruction so that the parser understands and uses the same while building the PDF page.

Comment: I add "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />" but nothig change. You can see my html in "[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976168/converting-html-with-arabic-letters-to-pdf]". Thank you.

Comment: @Ravinder I wish I could give you +100. I spent so much time dealing with this, all different messy libraries I have used etc. Thanks so much!

Comment: What if I do not have html source in string? Is there any way that I can give path of my HTML file and it will convert it to pdf?

Comment: `sb.toString() ` - what is `sb`?

Comment: Ya... I forgot to add its source variable. `sb` is the `StringBuffer` representation of `xhtml` or `html` content in context.

Comment: And you can read the `html` content from file and can store in `StringBuffer`

Comment: Sorry but I am using jsp page with elemnts adding dynamically. What should I do? My need is I want a print button and it should give me the snapshot of that page in pdf.

Comment: Is there a way to create the PDF on a LANDSCAPE? position

Comment: _**@Samarland**_: You can read and follow the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14600433/767881) given by [Bruno Lowagie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie), original developer of iText. Comments on that answer shall also be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You can use JTidy framework for this. This will convert HTML to XHTML and translate again to XSL-FO. This object can be used for generating PDF.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html