# iText - Rotate page content while creating PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I would like to produce a PDF that has pages in landscape. While it is possible to set the size of the page to landscape using:

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
```

this does not achieve what I want because any content that I add is still oriented left->right while I would like it to be bottom->top.

I.E. this is what I am getting:

[image: landscape with content left->right]

When what I want is:

[image: landscape with content bottom->top]

I have been able to achieve the desired output by [opening the PDF after it has been created and rotating it](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=232) using iText, but I would like a solution that lets me rotate it immediately with iText after adding content to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excellent question. If I was able to upvote it twice, I would!

You can achieve what you want with a `PdfPageEvent`:

```
public class RotateEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
    }
}
```

You should use this `RotateEvent` right after you've defined the writer:

```
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
    writer.setPageEvent(new RotateEvent());
```

Note that I used `SEASCAPE` to get the orientation shown in your image. You can also use `LANDSCAPE` if you want the page to be oriented in the other direction.

I need to remember this question once I start writing a third edition of "iText in Action". It's a nice example of when to use the `onStartPage()` event.

Comment: That worked! I found that I didn't need to create the RotateEvent though, I just used `writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.SEASCAPE);` immediately after creating the PdfWriter since I am always creating a single page.

Comment: You're right, that works too, but each time the extra entry of the page dictionary was "used", it's gone. In your case, that doesn't matter because you're only creating one page!