# How to implement a PdfPageEventHelper that rotates some pages, but not others

Tags: itext

My app generates a PDF report which sometimes contains tables that have been rotated (actually the tables are transposed, and the text is rotated). For pages that contain these tables, I want the page to be rotated to landscape so the user doesn't have to rotate it in their browser or cock their head sideways. It seems the best way to do this would be to follow the example that is shown here: [iText - Rotate page content while creating PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591689/itext-rotate-page-content-while-creating-pdf)

However, in order to do this, I would need to check whether or not the current page contains a table that has been rotated. How can I do this? Is it possible to do this in the 2.x version as well?

Comment: Regarding version 2.x, please read http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Interesting. I'll do that soon. I was using the AbstractPDFView class provided by Spring 2.5 which has a dependency on iText 2.x. Do you know how this would be done with the new version? I've read through a lot of documentation and have a copy of the 2.x version of iTextInAction, but I didn't see how to do this.

Comment: I don't know anything about Spring's implementation of iText. Did you ask the people at VMWare?