# Cannot rotate a PDF iText page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to rotate several PDF pages to get a SEASCAPE or LANDSCAPE portrait but I cannot figure out what I am missing. Here is my code

```
public void createSizedPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Rectangle one = new Rectangle(290,120);
    one.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);

    Document document = new Document(one,5,5,5,5);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    Rotate event = new Rotate();
    event.setOrientation(PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    // add some paragraphs and imgs here

    if(i != 0){
        event.setOrientation(PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
        document.newPage();             
    }           
    document.add(img);
   }        
    document.close();
}

public class Rotate extends PdfPageEventHelper {

     protected PdfNumber orientation = PdfPage.PORTRAIT;

    public void setOrientation(PdfNumber orientation) {
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, orientation);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591689/itext-rotate-page-content-while-creating-pdf) and this official documentation of iText [link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-orientation-and-rotation)

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to open the document. You need to add the following line after you have set the event:

```
document.open();
```

Because you forgot this line, you get an exception informing you that the document isn't open when you add an image.

Please be more specific the next time you post a question. For instance: share the exception that is thrown when you run your code. When I first read your code, I thought: *This code is taken literally from the official documentation, why wouldn't it work?*

I assumed that there was something wrong with the page rotation, but after reading your question a third time, I realized that you didn't tell us what is wrong, so I took another look at your code, and then I saw the culprit: the ;issing `open()` statement. I would have seen it immediately if you had shared the exception that is thrown.

Comment: actually i didn't forget the document.open() statement so i'm not gettin any errors,  it was deleted by mistake when i copy/paste the code,  and yes these line are from the documentation `Rotate event = new Rotate();
    event.setOrientation(PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
    writer.setPageEvent(event);` and the Rotate class as well. what i can't understand i don't get a SEASCAPE pageas it should, and it does work fine with some simple examples that i've tried .

Comment: OK, then you should fix your question: add the `document.open()`, explain that you don't get any errors, and explain that the pages aren't rotated. Ideally, you should also add a PDF that shows the behavior so that we can check the page dictionary (not a screen shot, but the actual PDF). Without it, nobody can help you, because **as you yourself admit**, the examples work perfectly. Only your specific code doesn't work. We don't see what is specific for your code based on your broken copy/paste sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE.rotate(),5,5,5,5);
```