# Java Generate a PDF with flying Saucer

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer, apache-fop

The jar i am using is from the maven [repo](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22flying-saucer-pdf%22)

The code i am testing is from a previous stack [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493837/how-to-export-html-page-to-pdf-format)

I fear it might be outdated because the libraries are depreciated. When testing the following code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        // if you have html source in hand, use it to generate document object
        renderer.setDocumentFromString( "C:/Users/Goran/Documents/Documents/Development/workspace/FlyingSaucer/data/input/report.xhtml" );
        renderer.layout();

        String fileNameWithPath = "C:/Users/Goran/Documents/Documents/Development/workspace/FlyingSaucer/data/output/" + "PDF-FromHtmlString.pdf";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameWithPath );
        renderer.createPDF( fos );
        fos.close();

        System.out.println( "File 2: '" + fileNameWithPath + "' created." );
    }

}
```

I have the following error this this line: `renderer.createPDF( fos );`

```
The type com.lowagie.text.DocumentException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Anyone able to shed some light on this, or suggest the best way to create a pdf document in java? I have both XML and XHTML documents available.

**EDIT** When i add the com.lowagie.text library from the [repo](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.lowagie.text)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xhtmlrenderer/extend/UserAgentCallback
    at test.main(test.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xhtmlrenderer.extend.UserAgentCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Am i even using the right libraries / the most up to date ones?

Can someone who has the most recent libraries or know a repo where they are stored link them?

**EDIT 2** Abandoned idea of using flying saucer and using ApacheFop as suggested. Current error is:

```
Mar 10, 2016 9:58:23 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
Mar 10, 2016 9:58:23 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
Mar 10, 2016 9:58:23 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #1.
```

Comment: You need to find the jar containing `com.lowagie.text.DocumentException ` and add it to your classpath

Comment: @Scary Wombat i tried that as well, throws a different error. There are a lot of versions of the libraries and no guide that i'm not sure which to use :(

Comment: Yep, rinse and repaet for `org/xhtmlrenderer/extend/UserAgentCallback`

Comment: @Scary Wombat That doesn't help when it's asking for depreciated libraries from 2006 and 2008 instead of the 2015 ones. These examples are out of date :(

Comment: try using apacheFOP then

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thanks! Changed to FOP, got some warings/errors that i'm not sure what they are but the pdf does render so that's good at least.

Comment: The warning messages means you have to [configure the fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460) (disclosure: old answer of mine).

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple Maven project with the following depencency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8</version>
    </dependency>
```

I created a test class with excatly the code that you posted above and was able to compile it without issue.  This is what Eclipse shows as the Maven dependencies:

[image]

Note that I had to change this line for the code to work:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString("<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> <em>world</em>!</body></html>");
```

... since the string should be the HTML content itself any not the path to the file.

The PDF looked like this:

[image]

I hope that helps...

---

Answer (score 0):

I am using the exact same dependency as you mentioned, so that should not be the problem.

However, you are definitely using the method `setDocumentFromString` in a wrong way. Instead of:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString( "C:/some/path/report.xhtml" );
```

the input parameter must be the HTML itself, NOT the path to it. Like this:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString( "<html><body>some content</body></html>" );
```

Alternatively, (and preferably) use the `setDocument` method which takes as input a path in form of String or a File. [see JavaDoc](http://javadox.com/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5/9.0.3/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextRenderer.html)