# JavaFx html formatted text in pdf using iText with formatation

Tags: java, html, javafx, itext, html-editor

Is it possible to set a formatted `HTML`-Text (Color, Alignment, ...) from a `HTMLEditor` to an "editable" PDF using `iText`.

I didn't find anything on the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: You can probably do that with iText 7 + the pdfHTML add-on, but you need to explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is (as Amedee suggested) using pdfHTML.
It's an iText7 add-on that converts HTML5 (+CSS3) into pdf syntax.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
        "<b>This text should be written in bold.</b>", // html to be converted
        new PdfWriter(
            new File("C://users/user2002/output.pdf")  // destination file
        )
    );
```

To learn more, go to https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution in this post using `The Flying Saucer`: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084884/8095847)