# how to convert an HTML page to a PDF document with Java?

Tags: java, pdf, web

I have a web application (built with Java).

The user fills in a bunch of field, some stuff is dynamically assembled, and the read only form is presented to the user, then the user clicks "Approve" if they're okay with everything.

On the "Approve" click, I need to build a PDF version of the HTML page and store the PDF away in a database for safe keeping.

I've doing some digging, but not finding what I need.  What's an *easy* open source way of making a PDF version of my HTML page?

I found iText, but it requires a commercial license (a show-stopper, unfortunately).  Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Similar question probably http://stackoverflow.com/q/633780/776084

Comment: Note that iText also offers an AGPL licence (which might also be a show-stopper) but I mention for completeness...

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache™ FOP (Formatting Objects Processor)](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) - most advanced for java. FAQ: [Can I use FOP to convert XHTML or HTML files to PDF?](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#xhtml-to-pdf) . But it is not a very easy way, sorry.