# Exporting dynamic java web application to PDF?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, zk

I am completing an application using the ZK framework which runs under tomcat 7.0. It is basically a custom calculator which provides end users with total costs of items based on an input amount.

Could you please recommend me with the best solution to export the contents to PDF? is this possible? as a user will need to store the values in a PDF format on their machine. Roughly speaking I need to export the contents on screen into a PDF format and then download that onto a users machine.

Thank you

Have a nice day

Comment: You should show us your attempt so far ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

ZK provide very good integration with Jasper Report ,so here you can use jasper Report Integration with ZK.
Now the question here how we can do this there are plenty of way like .
Here you can check
[Create_a_Report_with_ZK_using_iReport_and_JasperReports](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/April/Create_a_Report_with_ZK_using_iReport_and_JasperReports)

[integrate-zk-with-jasper-report](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2012/10/integrate-zk-with-jasper-report.html)

[integrate-dyanmic-jasper-reprot-with-zk](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2012/10/integrate-dyanmic-jasper-reprot-with-zk.html)

**Note:-** All this Example done for ZK EE.