# how to convert HTML files to PDF in Java?

Tags: java, html, api, pdf-generation

I am trying to develop an application which takes a html file or url as input and renders the same as PDF file. I am using yahp for this purpose. I have imported the `yahp.jar` file, however I am stuck with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.allcolor.yahp.cl.converter.CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerTransformer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CClassLoader.findClass(CClassLoader.java:1495)
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CClassLoader.findClass(CClassLoader.java:1477)
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CClassLoader.loadClass(CClassLoader.java:2056)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.getTransformer(CYaHPConverter.java:383)
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf(CYaHPConverter.java:246)
at HtmlToPDF.htmlToPdfFile(HtmlToPDF.java:74)
at HtmlToPDF.main(HtmlToPDF.java:52)
SEVERE: Error while getting   transformer 'org.allcolor.yahp.cl.converter.CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerTransformer' ! :        org.allcolor.yahp.cl.converter.CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerTransformer
org.allcolor.yahp.converter.IHtmlToPdfTransformer$CConvertException
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf(CYaHPConverter.java:255)
at HtmlToPDF.htmlToPdfFile(HtmlToPDF.java:74)Done

at HtmlToPDF.main(HtmlToPDF.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf(CYaHPConverter.java:247)
... 2 more
Destroying YAHP ClassLoader Tree
Exception in thread "AWT-Windows" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: seems like you forgot to include some dependence-libs

Comment: You can also read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

iText “XML Worker” allows developers to convert XML files to PDF documents in a programmer-friendly way. iText can also convert HTML to PDF with the CSS style implemented on HTML elements.
Look at [this](http://hmkcode.com/itext-html-to-pdf-using-java/)

Comment: I am using itext to convert html files into pdf,in doing so the text is getting converted but the image is getting lost. Please help!