# Convert .jsp or html file to pdf

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf

Does anyone knows how to convert a jsp or html file to pdf format using Java? Something else than flying saucer and/or iText?

Comment: want to use aspose words for java?

Comment: Never used it before, Im going to check it out and let you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML files to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using YaHP Converter, if somebody else wonders, just take a look at their site. 
http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/

Answer (score 0):

[PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com) converts HTML/CSS to PDF and RTF. For JSP to PDF conversion it is supplied with an easy-to-use custom JSP taglib.

Comment: Yes thank you, I tried with it and its a nice tool!