# Download a JSP page as PDF

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf

I have a link on my JSP page. The functionality of this link is to download the entire JSP page as a PDF file. This PDF file is very much like a screenshot of the JSP page. How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, U can convert HTML table from your JSP to PDF.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269556/convert-jsp-or-html-file-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can call a **javaScript** function from that link,and in that function u can change content type of the page dynamically as "**application/pdf**".