# When button Clicked, download jsp table in the form of PDF

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

I have jsp with one button download pdf.
[image: Here is a table with some welcome phrases and some geter or setter properties]

```
<HTML>
<body>
 <%
        String value = "12324";
        String email = "abc@gmail.com";
        %>
<h3>Welcome to the system. To download this form click on "Download PDF" </h3> 
                     <jsp:useBean id="myBean" scope="session" class="VU.viechelInfoClass" />
                     <jsp:getProperty name="myBean" property="model" />
                     <table border="1" width="20%" height="50" >
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>#</th>
                                 <th>1</th>
                                 <th>2</th>
                                 <th>3</th>
                                 <th>4</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody width="20%" height="50" >
                             <tr>
                                 <td><%= value %> </td>
                                 <td><%= email %></td>
                                 <td> email </td>
                                 <td>name </td>
                                 <td>Address </td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td> id </td>
                                 <td> Quiz</td>
                                 <td> email </td>
                                 <td>name</td>
                                 <td>Address </td>
                             </tr>
                             
                         </tbody>
                     </table>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Download PDF" />


    </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

When download button clicked I got this jsp in pdf format but it is not showing data properly in table? Is this possible?  How to do it please?
[image: it shows this type of output in pdf :( I want to get whole table properly]

Please share some informative tips.

Comment: You are going to need to use a PDF library (like **IText**) to recreate the page yourself if you don't wan't to use the Browser Print Tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save a jsp page as pdf in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386585/how-to-save-a-jsp-page-as-pdf-in-java) or any other page for this [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=jsp%20page%20pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a simple alternative, that is print pdf 
Code for button is here

```
<input type="submit" value="Download PDF" name="download" onclick="window.print()" />
```

Now I am able to print it in any format doc, pdf etc and entries will look like as given in jsp table format.