# Converting XLSX to XSL-FO to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, xsl-fo, xlsx

Apaches POI has a `ExcelToFoConverter` class that allows to convert xls files to XSL-FO. Since I use XLSX files, I am worried that I will have data loss when I use this converter. POI does not offer an explicit converter for xlsx files. However, I saw that someone used the `ExcelToFoConverter` for xlsx files.

1. Can I just use the mentioned converter class for xlsx files?
2. If I can't, what are other options?
3. Or is there a much better solution for converting XLST files to PDF without(!) having a program like LibreOffice or OpenOffice on the server?

Comment: Try it and see? Then submit patches for anything missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get from XLSX > HTML:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/converter/ExcelToHtmlConverter.html

http://allstarnix.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/use-java-to-convert-excel-to-html.html

then you can use easily get from HTML > PDF using FlyingSaucer.

https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Commercial solutions would include Aspose Cells for Java:

http://www.aspose.com/java/excel-component.aspx

Comment: XSL-FO has limitations (read wiki page). It is better off to use CSS3-paged (html) as Alan points

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding FlyingSaucer. I Just gave it a try and it works pretty well.

Comment: According to javadoc of class  ExcelToHtmlConverter: "Converts xls files (97-2007) to HTML file". So, ExcelToHtmlConverter can not convert xlsx files to html.

Answer (score 0):

For option 3 I have used iText to create PDF files. See the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an xsl sometime ago that did Excel XML format conversion to XSL FO. It is available in the Cool tools section of the RenderX website.

http://www.renderx.com/files/demos/cooltools/Excel2FO.zip