# Having Freemarker-like templates for PDF generation (with itext)

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, freemarker

In Java Project, i would like to use a Freemarker or something similar to it 
([Quick start guide](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_all.html)), but to generate a PDF file (textual), with IText for example.

Of cource, the workflow could be like that:

> Template (Freemarker) -> Text (IText) -> PDF

...but I feel it is kind of a naive approach. I want to have in the PDF some formattings, tables, etc.

Anyone knows how to design it properly?

Answer (score 1):

As PDF is a binary format, the best seems to generate some standard text format for which there exists a PDF conversion.

```
Texts --[FreeMarker]--> HTML or      --[HTML-to-iText]--> PDF
                        DocBook XML
```

This also allows validation of the FreeMarker templates.

Comment: thanks! 
can you link me something the HTML or XML to I Text thing please?

Comment: A search "java html to pdf" yielded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf but I would do a bit of research to current converters. There are many HTML versions, tricky things like images. DocBook XML, especially the more tractable new Simple DocBook XML is might be less open-ended (=more complete features) than HTML; they can do PDF generation, with niceties as page footers. Other formats exist with PDF generation, **epub** I believe.