# Convert HTML-Text to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf

I want to create pdf files with Java. I get a HTML-String (with tables etc.). This content is to be written to the file. I found libs like iText but this is not for commercial use. Is it possible to solve my problem with PdfBox? I must not use iText!

Thanks for help!

Comment: If your app is not for commercial use, you can use iText, and iText certainly can be used for commercial use also.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf There are multiple solutions and you can use older iText versions.

Comment: I need a solution without iText! I must not use it...

Comment: There is no solution with PDFBox.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for all informations