# How to convert TestNG report index.html to pdf

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to convert TestNG report to PDF.
I have tried so many options present on google but all are converting HTML code to PDF but I required replica of index.html or emailable report to PDF.

Many are offering different plug-ins.. I do not have problem with them unless there presentation and information​ they sharing is some what equalvent to TestNG report.

I understand the index.html have other dependansies like css and other things like images.

Can anyone suggest a good option.
Please specify the jars required and import if possible.

It will really help :)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. I did a quick google and there are a LOT of options. Which of them have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pdf report, you can use this TestNG extension: http://uttesh.com/pdfngreport/

Or you can write your own by implementing [the IReporter interface](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters), and maybe combined with [IText](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html) or any other pdf generation lib.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to use above plugin and you just want to convert your index.html, you can refer the following thread.

[A java library for converting xml/html to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685395/a-java-library-for-converting-xml-html-to-pdf)