# how to generate PDF file from a page with TextBox in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to make a form inside an asp.net page and then generate the form with inputted value into pdf. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Pdf from webpage in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013538/generating-pdf-from-webpage-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

For creating pdf there is one perfect framework=>[itextpdf](http://itextpdf.com/)